# Having a problem in importing openai facing with ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__pydantic_core)

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I have run my first line of my code which is `import openai` in my visual studio code on Widows 10 and face with this unknown error! I read several pages but can't find out the main issue! can anyone help me to solve this problem.
Openai version == 1.7.1
python version == 3.11.7
Error: ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__pydantic_core)

[ImportError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICT6e.png)

Comment: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

Comment: I checked this link, the problem is I am in the first step of just importing openai after installing it. I installed openai today and I mentioned the version ofopenai.

Comment: please include all the error message you get.

Comment: The error is compete in the picture that I shared in the question.